# ImageIO.read( new URL(imagePath)) is not responding for HTTPS URLS

Tags: java, image, aem, javax.imageio, aem-6

My code is working as expected on localhost starter kit but when I deployed it to development server my below code is taking around 2-3 mins and after that it says

```
Invalid URL
The requested URL "http://%5bNo%20Host%5d/index.html?", is invalid.
Reference #9.3d7c4117.1550338465.3d54af04
```

My code is as follows:

```
imagePath = "https://i.imgur.com/TrNzuMY.jpg";
Image image = null;
image = ImageIO.read( new URL(imagePath))
```

Is this something AEM on development server is not allowing to access external URLs?
This is AEM 6.3 and this code is called in a JSP which is getting called by another JSP using AJAX GET request.

Edit (After Sumanta Pakira response): This is only happening when passed URL is Secure i.e. HTTPS, for HTTP URLs it is working as expected.

Comment: Is the "i.imgur.com" in same AEM server or different server?

Comment: On a different server

Comment: Sounds like a proxy or filewall issue related to the network the dev server is connected to.

Comment: I tried this with the image present on the same server but still the same issue.

Comment: Is your local AEM server HTTPS enabled? I think not, and this is the reason it works in your local and you can read about CROS: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kt/platform-repository/using/cors-security-article-understand.html

Comment: It is working for http urls. Great catch @SumantaPakira. But I have to use https. I can't change the server config. Is there anything that can be done?

Comment: If this is an HTTPS issue, try using an HttpClient to make the get request for testing and log the response error, there can be different reasons and this will help arrow it down.

Comment: This question seems to be network-related, and not really specific to ImageIO (you can reproduce the same effect using `URL.openStream()`). You might get better answers, if you re-write and re-tag it with network-related tags.

Answer (score -1):

There are two solutions :

1. Add the server (i.imgur.com) certificate into your AEM server trust store.
2. You can look at this [example](https://gist.github.com/zhong-j-yu/22af353e2c5a5aed5857)

Comment: There is no evidence of a certificate problem.

Comment: @user207421, I am sure this certificate is self-signed, Have you read the comment above? or ask for information before marking it as incorrect!

Comment: I tried the second option as I can't change the AEM trust store. But it didn't work.